# android: Save files in internal storage in a directory publicly

Tags: android

I am trying to save images in a directory inside app file dir publicly. By publicly, I mean that I will be able to use action view intent on it.

```
/** Saves the bitmap to app storage */
    public int SaveBitmap(Bitmap bitmap, String filename, Boolean scan){

        // Save the file
        OutputStream os = null;

        String path = context.getFilesDir() + "/MyAppName/";
        File file = new File(path);
        if(!file.isDirectory())file.mkdirs();
        path += (filename + ".png");
        try {
            os = new BufferedOutputStream(new FileOutputStream(path,true));
            //os = mContext.openFileOutput(, Context.MODE_PRIVATE);
            bitmap.compress(CompressFormat.PNG, 100, os);
            os.flush();
            os.close();
            bitmap.recycle();
        } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
            return 1; //Failure
        }

        File fileR = new File(path);

        fileR.setReadable(true, false);
        // Show in Gallery
        if(scan) ShowInGallery(filename);

        return 0; // SUCCESS

    }
```

This piece of code doesn't do the job, the files are still created in private mode.

Using:

```
context.openFileOutput(filename + ".png", Context.MODE_WORLD_READABLE);
```

I was able to open them publicly, but I cannot save the file in a directory in that.

Note that I am targetting users that do not have SD cards, that is why I am not using External Storage.

What can I do?

Comment: If it's important the images remain "private" unless acted on, then you will need to implement a `ContentProvider` to give other apps or intents temporary access to your data. If all images are to be accessible, you can simply store them externally, as the answers below explain.

Comment: read the doc for `context.getFilesDir`

Comment: @njzk2 - doesn't help, thats internal storage.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think that the safest thing to do in my case is to use `Environment.getExternalStoragePublicDirectory (String type)`
And if an exception is caught, I will save it to internal storage using normal getFilesDir. I haven't found a way to make that folder inside app data readable publicly.

This is because getExternalStoragePublicDirectory may fail if the device should have an SD card but it is not mounted. So you can't depend on it.

Comment: Excuse me but why did you down vote this? It works perfectly fine and it does what I needed it to do.

Answer (score 8):

You're going to want to use `Environment.getExternalStoragePublicDirectory (String type)` or `Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory` as the root of your file directory.  See the [documentation](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/os/Environment.html#getExternalStoragePublicDirectory%28java.lang.String%29) for more details.

Edit:

From the Environment documentation under `getExternalStorageDirectory ()`:

> Note: don't be confused by the word "external" here. This directory
>   can better be thought as media/shared storage. It is a filesystem that
>   can hold a relatively large amount of data and that is shared across
>   all applications (does not enforce permissions). Traditionally this is
>   an SD card, but it may also be implemented as built-in storage in a
>   device that is distinct from the protected internal storage and can be
>   mounted as a filesystem on a computer.

All "External" means is that it's external to your application, or public.  So, if an SD card is available, then this method defaults to that storage directory.  If the device doesn't use an SD card, the device's build-in storage is used.

Comment: I do not want to use External Storage, this is because I want to target users that do no have SD cards installed.

Comment: "External" storage doesn't just mean external storage.  See edit in a moment.

Comment: "If no SD card is available, the device's build-in storage is used." is not necessarily true - a device intended to use an SD card as it's implementation of ExternalStorage **will not have an external storage available** when that card is removed.  The question as asked is an entirely legitimate one, though there *may be* alternatives, and some components may not *even attempt* to access files located in application directories, even if they would actually have access rights to them.

Comment: You're right, my wording was off.  However, I was mainly trying to make the point that just because a device doesn't "have" an SD card doesn't necessarily mean that it won't have external storage.  If getExternalStorageDirectory() won't suffice, then some other approach, such as a content provider would be necessary.

Comment: @Submersed - no, that is not true either.  It is possible to make files in the application directory world readable.

Comment: True, but frowned upon.  Hence Context.MODE_WORLD_READABLE's deprecation.